# Whoops, looks like something went wrong. + laravel log

Tags: laravel

Im getting error **Whoops, looks like something went wrong** when im trying to open my site.
Laravel.log below.
Any ideas? 
I can not find the reason.

```
  [2018-02-12 15:54:33] local.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined offsetlocal.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/GameController.php:1187
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/GameController.php(1187): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/var/www/html/a...', 1187, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/storage/framework/views/d9e75a6376cb0f1bf817fd268d5b1ee4(70): App\Http\Controllers\GameController::getActualCurs(0)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(42): include('/var/www/html/s...')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(58): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/var/www/html/s...', Array)
```

Comment: `app/Http/Controllers/GameController.php:1187` check that line, it's throwing undefined offset

Comment: '#1185 preg_match('#<Valute ID="R01235">.*?.<Value>(.*?)</Value>.*?</Valute>#is', $str, $value);
#1187 $usd = $value[1];
#1189 $dollar = $rub/$usd;
#1191  return round($dollar,3);
#1192 }`

Comment: Your question is still not well constructed. Lay out the problem before the sharing the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Then describe your strategy thus far, code setup + conditions, and the errors/issues. Also state 'obvious' context that you already know, so that people understand what you have tried. See also [1](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Undefined offsets occur when you try to read an element of an array that is not defined. In your code this happens on line 1187 in GameController.php. You can check [if they key exist](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) before using it.

```
if (array_key_exists('key', $array)) {
    // do something with it
}
```

Comment: Im sorry, but im newbie. Can you explain me how i exectly should do that?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea how to make this any easier than my current answer.